# how does visual studio debug optimization work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization

I tried to find the answer for this, on the internet but I couldn't find any.

what I'm trying to say here is that in visual studio there is an option inside the project properties called optimization that is by default set to enable in release mode an disable in debug mode. what does this option do exactly ? I mean it obviously makes the program run faster but how ? what happen behind the scene ?

I'm a decent programmer but it's completely fine to give me a complicated answer, I can take it as a start point do more researches

Comment: C++ has the *as-if rule*: compiler is allowed to do anything, as long as the observable result is the same. What the compiler does exactly - it's completely up to that compiler, you need to read the documentation of that compiler. If you want to read about optimizations in general, I guess there should be plenty resources on the internet, this topic is not C++ exclusive.

Comment: Debug mode prioritises being able to step line by line (or even expression by expression) with an attached debugger. Release mode priorities being fast. You might be able to attach a debugger to release mode code, but it is much harder to understand what is going on, when.

Comment: For an overview of compiler optimizations you could start with [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Optimization* is a compiler feature which tries to analyze the program and change it to be faster (or sometimes smaller).

When optimization is turned off, the compiler creates assembly code for exactly what you typed. When it's turned on, it changes it. This usually confuses debuggers and takes longer to compile, but the code runs faster.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        arr[x] = rand();
    }
}
```

Without optimization, `arr[x] =` is going to: get the value of `x` from memory, multiply it by 4, add the address of `arr`, and store the value there.

With optimization, the compiler is going to notice that it can just add 4 to the address each time the loop runs - it's going to change your code into this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    int *current = arr;
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        *current = rand();
        current++;
    }
}
```

Also, it's not going to load `current` and `x` from memory each time it needs them, and save them to memory each time they change - it's going to choose one register to hold the value of `current`, one register to hold the value of `x`, and *keep* them in those registers. It might not need any memory at all.

Using a debugger might be harder, because if you pause the program when it's running `current++;`, it won't be able to show you what the program is doing, because this instruction isn't in the source code! (Most likely, it'll point to the `arr[x] = rand()` line, or maybe the `i++` line)

If the compiler *really* wants to, it *might* even decide that since the loop always runs exactly 10 times, it can just do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    arr[0] = rand();
    arr[1] = rand();
    arr[2] = rand();
    arr[3] = rand();
    arr[4] = rand();
    arr[5] = rand();
    arr[6] = rand();
    arr[7] = rand();
    arr[8] = rand();
    arr[9] = rand();
}
```

Now there's no `x` variable and no loop at all. The code's longer, though.

Actually, wait a minute, why are we generating these values we don't need? Nobody cares what values are in `arr`. So it can do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    rand();
    rand();
    rand();
    rand();
    rand();
    rand();
    rand();
    rand();
    rand();
    rand();
}
```

... it can't delete the `rand()` calls, though, because it doesn't know whether the `rand()` function does anything important. But it *does* know that you aren't using its return value and so there's no point saving it anywhere.

So that's what optimization is about. The compiler rearranges the program to try and make it faster. I've just shown you some simple optimizations, but they can be much trickier than this.

Comment: turns out it was simpler than I thought, thanks man, I also found this video that was very simple about how optimization works: youtube.com/watch?v=-nr8FnzgfYw